# When importing random number from module in two different files, why are they the same?

Tags: python, import, module

If I have a file `foo.py`, which contains

```py
# foo.py
from random import randint

r = randint(0, 100)
```

And I have 2 other files, `bar.py` and `main.py` and we run `main.py`

```py
# bar.py
from foo import r  # gets random number

bars_r = r
```

```py
# main.py
from bar import bars_r
from foo import r  # gets random number, equal to random number from bar.py?

print(r == bars_r)  # True
```

I am confused at how `r` and `bars_r` can be equal in `main.py`.  `bar.py` is importing `r` from `foo.py`, so my understanding is it runs `foo.py`, getting a random number which we can set to `bars_r`. We import `bars_r` into `main.py`. Also in `main.py`, we import `r` from `foo.py`, so wouldn't it run `foo.py` again, producing a different random number? How does python seem to save the result of the `randint` function ran in `foo.py`, so that it can be imported into 2 different modules and have the same value?

Comment: `import` doesn't mean "run this thing". It means "give me this resource, performing any necessary initialization that *hasn't been performed yet*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also in main.py, we import r from foo.py, so wouldn't it run foo.py again, producing a different random number?

No. When a module is imported for the first time, it is loaded, executed, and the result is stored in `sys.modules`. The second time, the existing module object is simply retrieved from `sys.modules`.

In normal operations, a module's top level code is run *once* per Python instance / process.

This is trivial to check by adding observable side-effects e.g. just print something in `foo.py`.

Having every import leading to a different module object not only would be rather expensive, it would be extremely odd as e.g. the classes defined by a module would not necessarily be compatible *with itself* (as importing the module twice would create two completely different class objects in memory).